# Augmented reality, create my own simple app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, camera, augmented-reality

all i need is to create an augmented reality simple app, where i save manually an image in the application main bundle, and the camera in the application should track or recognize this image and do any action in the application when it is recognized,
All the posts here redirect to buy ready online products,
can any one help me in a tutorial or some basics and concepts how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had great experience with the free Vuforia framework. There good sample projects to understand how the framework works.

You can [download the SDK here](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk).

The sample project you would need to take a look at is the [User Defined Target sample](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sample-apps/user-defined-target-sample-app).

Qualcomm's support team on the Vuforia Support forums are very kind and offers great support if you are facing any problems with the framework.

Comment: Hi I am starting to implement some custom furniture based Augmented Reality ios app something like Augment.Can you tell me what would be a good starting point? I have found  something vuforia,Metaio,Wikitude?
Is Vuforia fully free?

Comment: I haven't tried Metaio or Wikitude, but I have worked quite a lot with Vuforia. It is fully free and works quite well for both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [ARToolkit](https://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=5_iOS:ios_about). Its an open source framework available for most platforms